# Javascript: order of parent/child object instantiation

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, and would like to understand more about the order it instantiates parent/child objects. More specifically, I would like to understand the following snippet from the compiler/browser perspective.

```
var parent = {
  child: {
    field1: "value1",
    field2: "value2"
  },
  someOtherField: parent.child.field1, // => Error
  someOtherField: this.child.field1    // => Error
};
```

Both `Error` lines in the snippet above will generate the same error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'field1' of undefined
```

So it seems when the browser looks at `someOtherField` line, `parent.child` is still `undefined`, and therefore `parent.child.field1` is illegal. Could someone share some insights on why this is happening, and what is the exact sequence of instruction is the browser trying run with the above code snippet? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @RobG! That makes sense. I changed `this` to `parent`, and it is still the same error. What would be the explanation for this?

Comment: That *parent.child* doesn't exist yet. ;-) *parent* exists because it was declared. The assignment of the object to *parent* will only occur once the object is fully parsed and created, so until the closing `}` *parent* will keep its value prior to the assignment (i.e. undefined).

Comment: But the error message seems to suggest `parent.child` already exist, and is `undefined`? Is this how JavaScript work?

Comment: `this` depends on how you call a function, there's no function there; `this` is the global object then. You have to declare `someOtherField` seperately, like `parent.someOtherField = parent.child.field1`

Comment: Since the local `parent` variable hasn't been created, you're accessing the global variable `window.parent`. Try using a different variable name, you'll get a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code (dealing with one issue at a time):

```
var parent = {
  child: {
    field1: "value1",
    field2: "value2"
  },
  someOtherField: parent.child.field1 // => Error
};
```

The variable *parent* is created and initialised to *undefined* before any code is executed (so–called "hoisting"). Once execution begins, inspection of the progressive results appear to be that first the object is assigned to *parent*, then the internal properties are resolved.

So the first error message is like:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'parent.child.field1')
```

since *parent* is an object. From this result it's impossible to tell whether *parent* has a *child* property or not since it may have a *child* property initialised to *undefined*, or it might not have a child property at all. Either way, `parent.child` resolves to *undefined* and attempting to resolve a property of *undefined* returns a type error.

Note that given:

```
var parent = {
  one: 'one',
  two: parent.one
}

console.log(parent.one, parent.two) // one undefined
```

it can be seen that at the point of assigning a value to *parent.two*, *parent.one* was undefined.

As for:

```
  someOtherField: this.child.field1
```

the value of *this* will be the global object (window in a browser), and it doesn't have a *child* property so you get a similar error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.child.field1')
```

since there is no global *child*, so *this.child* returns *undefined* and attempting to resolve a property of *undefined* throws a type error.

Note also that:

```
  someOtherField: this.parent.child.field1
```

is equivalent to:

```
  someOtherField: parent.child.field1
```

and throws the same error.

The bottom line is that you shouldn't attempt to assign properties of partially completed objects. I'm sure there's an appropriate reference in ECMA-262, it will take a little while to find it.

Comment: Actually I am still a little confused. If `parent` is `undefined` at line `someOtherField: parent.child.field1`, shouldn't the error message be `Cannot read property 'child' of undefined` instead of `Cannot read property 'field1' of undefined`?

Comment: See updated answer. I was incorrect about the object not being assigned until it was complete, but close…

Comment: Thanks for all the clarification, @RobG!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with parent/child object instantiation. It has everything to do with hoisting.

All declarations in JavaScript are hoisted. Remember that variable declaration and variable definition are two separate things. For example, we can declare a variable `x` using `var x`. We define `x` using `x = someValue`. We can combine variable declaration and variable definition into a single construct as `var x = someValue`. However we are still declaring the variable and then defining it.

As I said all declarations in JavaScript are hoisted (i.e. they are lifted to the top of the function scope that they are declared in). For example, consider:

```js
alert(x);     // declared but not defined (undefined)
var x = null;
alert(x);     // declared and defined (null)
```

Here the variable declaration `var x` has been hoisted to the top of the scope. Variables that have been declared but have not been defined have the value `undefined` by default.

Compare the above code with:

```js
try {
  alert(x);
  x = null;
  alert(x);
} catch(e) {
  alert(e);  // ReferenceError: x is not defined
}
```

Here we have not declared `x`. Hence `x` is not hoisted. Thus when we try to print the value of `x` we get a `ReferenceError`. Note that it is not `undefined` because we haven't even declared it.

#### What's happening in your code

Now let's consider your code:

```
var parent = {
  child: {
    field1: "value1",
    field2: "value2"
  },
  someOtherField: parent.child.field1 // => Error
  someOtherField: this.child.field1   // => Error
};
```

This is the same as:

```
var parent; // hoisted; undefined

parent = {
  child: {
    field1: "value1",
    field2: "value2"
  },
  someOtherField: parent.child.field1 // => Error
  someOtherField: this.child.field1   // => Error
};
```

Before defining `parent`, it is `undefined`. Hence `parent.child.field1` is `undefined.child.field1` which is an error. Also `this` does not point to the object literal. Your mistake is that `parent` is not defined until after the object literal has been assigned to the variable (which is after `parent.child.field1` is evaluated).

What you can do is:

```
var parent = {
  child: {
    field1: "value1",
    field2: "value2"
  }
};

parent.someOtherField = parent.child.field1;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Aadit, that makes a lot of sense! But there is still a bit confusion: if `parent.child.field1` becomes `undefined.child.field1`, shouldn't the error message be `Cannot read property 'child' of undefined`? But I got `Cannot read property 'field1' of undefined` instead.